# Xcode source control - git add

Tags: xcode, git, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

How do you perform 'git add .' using Xcodes 'Source Control' function? Im having an issue where I updated my project to use 'Fabric' and Crashlytics, instead of using Crashlytics by itself. Every time I try and commit I get following message:

```
error: unable to index file Crashlytics.framework/Headers
fatal: updating files failed
```

I believe that If i can perform a 'git add .' and then 'commit' it will work. Im using Xcodes own Source Control function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird. Usually Xcode automatically adds all changed/new files to the commit automatically, and you can check any files you want in the left side of the window.

Regardless, you should be able to `cd` into the root directory of the Xcode project using Terminal and run git commands, like `git add .` manually.